# Transition both circles and text (within g element) in single general update pattern

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

Refactoring a question I posted ~30 minutes ago to make it better. I have the following code which uses the general update pattern to shift circles and text across the screen.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      mybutton: "A"
    }
  } 
    
  handleButtonChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ mybutton: event.target.value });
  };
      
  drawPoints() {
    const {mybutton} = this.state;
    
    const myData = [
      {x1:30, x2: 140, y1: 50, y2: 60, letter:"A"},
      {x1:50, x2: 150, y1: 60, y2: 120, letter:"B"},
      {x1:70, x2: 120, y1: 70, y2: 110, letter:"C"}
    ];
    
    const pointsLayer = d3.select('#my-svg').select('g.points')
    const xShift = function(d) {
      if(mybutton === "A") {
        return d.x1
      } else {
        return d.x2
      }
    }
    const yShift = function(d) {
      if(mybutton === "A") {
        return d.y1
      } else {
        return d.y2
      }
    }
    const textChange = function(d) {
      if(mybutton === "A") {
        return "white"
      } else {
        return "black"
      }
    }
    const circleColorChange = function(d) {
      if(mybutton === "A") {
        return "#FF0000"
      } else {
        return "#FFAAAA"
      }
    }


  pointsLayer
   .selectAll("circle")
   .data(myData)
   .exit()
   .transition()
    .duration(100)
    .attr('r', 0)
   .remove();

  pointsLayer
   .selectAll("circle")
   .data(myData)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => xShift(d))
    .attr("cy", d => yShift(d))
        .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("fill", d => circleColorChange(d))
//        .on("mouseover", ...)
//        .on("mouseout", ...)

    pointsLayer
   .selectAll("circle")
   .data(myData)
   .transition()
   .duration(1000)
   .delay((d, i) => i * 0.5)
    .attr("cx", d => xShift(d))
    .attr("cy", d => yShift(d))
        .attr("fill", d => circleColorChange(d))

    pointsLayer.selectAll("text").remove('*')
    pointsLayer
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(myData)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
            .attr('x', d => xShift(d))
            .attr('y', d => yShift(d))
            .text(d => d.letter)
  } 
      
  componentDidMount() {
    d3.select('#my-svg')
   .attr('width', '100%')
   .attr('height', '100%')
   .attr('viewBox', "0 0 " + (800) + " " + 600)  
   .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMaxYMax")  
  
    this.drawPoints();
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.drawPoints()
  }
  
  render() {
  
    const {mybutton} = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <form>
            <div>
              <label>
                  <input
                      type={"radio"}
                      value={"A"}
                      checked={mybutton === "A"}
                      onChange={this.handleButtonChange}
                  />
                  <span>{"A"}</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>
                  <input
                      type={"radio"}
                      value={"B"}
                      checked={mybutton === "B"}
                      onChange={this.handleButtonChange}
                  />
                  <span>{"B"}</span>
              </label>
            </div>
        </form>
      
        <svg id="my-svg">
          <g className="points" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id='root'>
  Come On Work!
</div>
```

Currently, I use a general update pattern for the circles. For the text, I simply remove the text showing and redraw it, however, I intend on using the general update pattern to slide the text as well.

**However**, my app has certain .on() mouseover and mouseout effects for the circles that are messed up when my cursor is over the text in the circle, since my .on() functions are placed on my circle elements only.

I would like to include **both** the circles and text each in their own  element, so that the structure is:

```
<g> 
  <circle>
  <text>
</g>
```

...and I would ideally like to apply the general update pattern a single time on the `g` elements, rather than once each for the circles and for the text. Then the .on() functions could be placed on the g elements as well, I presume.

Omitted from the example are other events that occur on transition, including changing the circle colors, radius, stroke, etc. using other helper functions (similar to xShfit, yShift but for these styles). Also, the text color would change as well in the transitions.

Per a response in the original question on this, I plan on reading through the D3 docs later today and tomorrow in detail to get better at general update pattern related D3 stuff, but for now, I am still seeking help with this problem, and hope that reposting it would draw more attention.

Any help refactoring this code so that only a single general update pattern would be needed to update the circles and text together, from within the  elements, would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

EDIT: edited with a function to change circle colors and another (unused) function that would hypothetically be used to change the text color.

EDIT2: also not sure if the general update pattern im currently using is good / correct in general. I use exit and enter and update, but not merge anywhere (not sure if needed)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, this seems to be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): if the only issue is the labels messing with the mouseover, just do...

```
.attr("pointer-events", "none")
```

... for the texts' selection.

Also, despite the fact that people normally like to put all elements of a given node (circle, text, etc...)  in a group, have in mind that this approach is not free from problems: for example, using exactly your coordinates and the circle's radius, the moment you put the text as the sibling of the circle in a `<g>` some circles in other groups will cover some texts.

All that being said, the pattern for the groups can be something like this:

```
let groups = pointsLayer.selectAll(".myGroups")
  .data(myData);

const groupsExit = groups.exit().remove();

const groupsEnter = groups.enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "myGroups");

groupsEnter.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("fill", d => circleColorChange(d));

groupsEnter.append("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("dominant-baseline", "central")
  .text(d => d.letter);

groups = groupsEnter.merge(groups)
  .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + xShift(d) + "," + yShift(d) + ")");
//        .on("mouseover", ...)
//        .on("mouseout", ...)
```

Notice that we don't (re)bind data for the exit selection, as you did in your code.

Have in mind that all the elements here are appending in the enter selection. If you need an update/enter/exit pattern for them as well, you'll have to nest it.

Finally, you said...

> I use exit and enter and update, but not merge anywhere (not sure if needed)

You don't need the `merge()` method at all, you can write any D3 code without it. We use it (as I did here) just to save some repeated lines.

Here is your updated code (with a smaller radius for the circles, so we can see all the circles' texts):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      mybutton: "A"
    }
  }

  handleButtonChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      mybutton: event.target.value
    });
  };

  drawPoints() {
    const {
      mybutton
    } = this.state;

    const myData = [{
        x1: 30,
        x2: 140,
        y1: 50,
        y2: 60,
        letter: "A"
      },
      {
        x1: 50,
        x2: 150,
        y1: 60,
        y2: 120,
        letter: "B"
      },
      {
        x1: 70,
        x2: 120,
        y1: 70,
        y2: 110,
        letter: "C"
      }
    ];

    const pointsLayer = d3.select('#my-svg').select('g.points')
    const xShift = function(d) {
      if (mybutton === "A") {
        return d.x1
      } else {
        return d.x2
      }
    }
    const yShift = function(d) {
      if (mybutton === "A") {
        return d.y1
      } else {
        return d.y2
      }
    }
    const textChange = function(d) {
      if (mybutton === "A") {
        return "white"
      } else {
        return "black"
      }
    }
    const circleColorChange = function(d) {
      if (mybutton === "A") {
        return "#FF0000"
      } else {
        return "#FFAAAA"
      }
    }

    let groups = pointsLayer.selectAll(".myGroups")
      .data(myData);

    const groupsExit = groups.exit().remove();

    const groupsEnter = groups.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "myGroups");

    groupsEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 20)
      .attr("fill", d => circleColorChange(d));

    groupsEnter.append("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("dominant-baseline", "central")
      .text(d => d.letter);

    groups = groupsEnter.merge(groups)
      .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + xShift(d) + "," + yShift(d) + ")");
    //        .on("mouseover", ...)
    //        .on("mouseout", ...)

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    d3.select('#my-svg')
      .attr('width', '100%')
      .attr('height', '100%')
      .attr('viewBox', "0 0 " + (800) + " " + 600)
      .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMaxYMax")

    this.drawPoints();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.drawPoints()
  }

  render() {

    const {
      mybutton
    } = this.state;
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      form >
      <
      div >
      <
      label >
      <
      input type = {
        "radio"
      }
      value = {
        "A"
      }
      checked = {
        mybutton === "A"
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleButtonChange
      }
      /> <
      span > {
        "A"
      } < /span> < /
      label > <
      /div> <
      div >
      <
      label >
      <
      input type = {
        "radio"
      }
      value = {
        "B"
      }
      checked = {
        mybutton === "B"
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleButtonChange
      }
      /> <
      span > {
        "B"
      } < /span> < /
      label > <
      /div> < /
      form >

      <
      svg id = "my-svg" >
      <
      g className = "points" / >
      <
      /svg> < /
      div >
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id='root'>
  Come On Work!
</div>
```

Comment: I am struggling here to re-implement the transitions. In the example above the circles no longer slide or change colors. I have tried adding the `.transition().delay()` code to `groups` and also to `groupsEnter` and no luck with either of them.

Comment: I guess what I'm not following is this line - `If you need an update/enter/exit pattern for them as well, you'll have to nest it` - i'm not quite sure where/how to nest the transitions

Comment: Well, as you know, the best way to get help is posting a new question with the specific details about the transition.